# All of the FB.api Suddenly not work on my app

Tags: php, facebook

My app was working well within these few day. But it was suddenly down with any revising.
I am trying to test the FB.api function, e.g. FB.login, FB.api('me/........'), it also not have any reply. The following is my original code. Is it any update about the FB.api?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId  : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>',
                status : true,
                cookie : true, 
                frictionlessRequests: true
            });

            FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);

                $('area').click(function() {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            FB.api('/me/permissions?access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken, function(response) {
                                alert("abc:" + response.authResponse.accessToken);

                                if (response.data[0].publish_stream == undefined) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                if (response.data[0].publish_stream == 1) {
                                    window.location.href = "like.php";
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'email,user_likes,publish_stream'});

                    return false;
                });
            });/**/
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed deprecation of `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize()` method in Facebook JS-SDK, using it will lead to error and will break your code.

In your case nothing after call to `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize()` is executed.

You should use [`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) instead and watch [Developer blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) for changes...

**Pro Tip**: Always, but always check your error console, error messages and exceptions are your friends!